# Any obvious simplification of $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have an expression that is made up of the sines of several angles unfortunately none of them are "friendly" angles such as $60^\circ$ or $45^\circ$ but sine occurs several times.

I get the feeling there might be some simplification I can do - or maybe this a situation where I reach for the calculator and present an approximate answer?

$x=\sin37^\circ \dfrac{(60\sin42^\circ)}{\sin101^\circ}$

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is a calculator job.

Comment: Simplifications are possible when angles sum up to 180 or 360, or half of them or double does that... I cannot find any relation of this kind, so I would say that all you can do is approximate.

Comment: Well, [not obvious...](http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/06/exact-values-sin-degrees.pdf)

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams ...how does he know that each of those answers is the simplest form?

Comment: @whytheq The results were derived [in this blog post](http://www.intmath.com/blog/how-do-you-find-exact-values-for-the-sine-of-all-angles/6212). My reply was mostly sardonic, I doubt there is an actual way to simplify the equation.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't know of any way other than to set $\sin(101^{\circ})$ as $\cos(11^{\circ})$, to make the numbers a little bit smaller.